# Change background image on link hover pure CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I am trying to get this effect at my site. example:https://rno1.com/

(scroll down to "we specialize in")

I am very new to HTML and CSS also I am working on WordPress which make it a little bit harder.
started to code with this question here at StackOverflow:

[Change body background image on hover with pure html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611675/change-body-background-image-on-hover-with-pure-html-css)

but I wanted to add a transition between the swapping images, also where do I need to change the font attributes?

```css
div.link>a {
  displya: inline-block !important;
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 100;
}

.bg1:hover+.background {
  background: url(https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/divorce-min.jpg);
}

.bg2:hover+.background {
  background: url(https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Fotolia_37279445_Subscription_Monthly_M-min.jpg);
}

.background {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#" class="bg1">bg1</a>
    <div class=background></div>
    <a href="#" class="bg2">bg2</a>
    <div class=background>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some opacity transition like below:

```css
div.link>a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.bg1+.background {
  background: url(https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/divorce-min.jpg);
}
.bg1:hover +.background {
  opacity:1;
}

.bg2+.background {
  background: url(https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Fotolia_37279445_Subscription_Monthly_M-min.jpg);
}
.bg2:hover +.background {
  opacity:1;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition:1s all;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#" class="bg1">bg1</a>
    <div class=background></div>
    <a href="#" class="bg2">bg2</a>
    <div class=background>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also optimize your code like below:

```css
div.link>a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg1:before {
  background: url(https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/divorce-min.jpg);
}
.bg1:hover:before {
  opacity:1;
}

.bg2:before {
  background: url(https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Fotolia_37279445_Subscription_Monthly_M-min.jpg);
}
.bg2:hover:before {
  opacity:1;
}

.bg:before {
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  z-index:-1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition:1s all;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#" class="bg1 bg">bg1</a>
    <a href="#" class="bg2 bg">bg2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! its really helped! but can you explain to me some more? I want some other hover effects maybe only on the text like the example page I posted. like grow...
also the images not in the middle of the page, tried to change the z-index but it broke the effect. and one last thing (sry to bother you really :S) if i paste this in section in wordpress page its changs the whole page backgroud or only the section background?

Comment: @BenZikri 1) if you want some effect on the text, consider transform (something like : `transform:translateX(10px)`) (2) to adjust the image, consider background-size and background-position to be able to put the image where you want (3) all depend on the code, as you can see in the first code the div are set position:absolute so if you need them to cover only a particular section, add position:relative to that section (ex: https://jsfiddle.net/t2b57s4r/)

Comment: thanks!! all your coding working great! can I ask 1 more thing? if I want to change the text on hover (or actually add Icon or something like the example how can i do that?
I know I stretch it :D

Comment: @BenZikri you can pick an icon from here :https://fontawesome.com/start for example and add it with the text and if you want to change the text, have a look to `transform` where you will be able to animate the text on hover

Comment: yes with transform I want to combine 2 things, 1 the background change on link hover. second, the link itself should grow and change to something else. for example: "Architectural Visualization" to "Architectural Visualization >>"
I am tryying to combine another fiddle i found here at the forum with no success: https://jsfiddle.net/pq3x0qvc/2/